# Pass multiple variables to document.querySelectorAll in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a JS function and I'm trying to pass multiple variables to a `document.querySelectorAll`.

It's working but only returns the first one.

I'm calling the function like this :

```
<body onload ="format_selectboxes('custom-select_1','custom-select_2','custom-select_3')" >
```

Here is the function :

```
function format_selectboxes(c1,c2,c3) {

            var x;
  
            x = document.querySelectorAll("."+c1,"."+c2,"."+c3);

            //alert(x)

            l = x.length;
            // alert(l)
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) { 
              // do stuff here 
}
```

How do I get the 3 working please ?

Thank you

Comment: It takes a single string, if you want commas in your selector, you'll need to make sure they are within the string, not separating arguments. `document.querySelectorAll("."+c1 + ", ."+c2 + ", ."+c3);`

Comment: Of course ... can't believe I missed it. Thanks.

Comment: Or use ```(`.${c1}, .${c2}, .${c3}`)``` for more readablilty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the selector wrong, the `,` does not work when appending string like that.

---

Currently you have:

```js
const c1 = 'foo', 
      c2 = 'bar',
      c3 = 'foobar';
const test = ("."+c1,"."+c2,"."+c3);

console.log(test);
```

Which logs `.foobar`, not the string you're expecting.

---

So when we alter that string concatenation to the format `.A, .B, .C` well see the correct value `.foo, .bar, .foobar`:

```js
const c1 = 'foo', 
      c2 = 'bar',
      c3 = 'foobar';
const test = (`.${c1}, .${c2}, .${c3}`);

console.log(test);
```